# How can I make FTP work smoothly in VirtualBox?

Tags: windows-7, macos, virtualbox, ftp

My host is OS X and I'm running Windows 7 as guest in VirtualBox 3.0.4. Network in NAT-mode. Having problems with FTP transfers. After a while (20-30 files) the transfers drops in speed and finally halts. I then have to reconnect and it works for another round.

Any ideas how to make this work?

Comment: Which way are you ftp'ing, i.e. which end is the client and which is the server?

Comment: The server is on a web host. I have tried a few and there are problem with all of them, so the issue must be in my network setup. 

I have tried two clients in my Win 7 host, FlashFXp and FileZilla, both of them is not working well and most of the time I can only transfer a few files.

I have read a bit about port forwarding and that it might fix the issue, gonna try that later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution. I switched adapter from NAT to bridged network (I think it's called like that on a english system). FTP transfers now works great.

Comment: Interesting, I don't even get connection in bridged mode, only in nat mode.